# Maintain Hover / Active over entire parent li element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists, href

I want it so that when I hover over a `<li>`, the entire element has a highlight of blue, and that the text within the `<li>` turns from black to white. I also want it so that when I click on the `<li>`, the `<li>` becomes active and the blue highlight and change from black to white text stays. I understand I have to use the `:hover` and `:active` attributes. Here is my attempt therefore:

HTML:

```
  <div class="facet">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="link">
          Name<span class="count">Count</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
//Changes the LINK text to white
.link:hover {
    background-color: #2897C5;
    color: #ffffff;
}

//Attempt to change the entire parent element text to white and have a blue highlight, but this doesn't seem to work
.facet li:active {
    background-color: #2897C5;
    color: #ffffff;
}

//Normal CSS for the link when it is not hovered over or clicked on
.link {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.3;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: #000;
}

//White text when you hover over the count
.count:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}

//Normal CSS when you don't hover over the count
.count {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    color: #bdbdbd;
}
```

NowI have a variety of issues with my attempt above. 
1. When I hover over the `<li>`, the entire thing turns blue which is great, and the "Name" text also turns white. However, the "Count" text only turns white when I have my mouse hover over that portion of the `<li>`.
2. When I click on the `<li>`, the element does not apply the active state (which is all white text and blue highlight) to the entire element.

Any ideas on how I can improve? Thanks!

Comment: That's not what `:active` means. It's not the currently active/chosen element, it's the ACTUAL active element - ie the second you click it, it's `active` - it's not maintained. To maintain the look, you'll have to have some sort of either server-side check for the right element to make active, or some javascript check to make it active.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better version with a lot less CSS: (no solution for the active-bit, but that will have to be solved outside CSS)

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  }
.facet li:hover,.facet li:hover .link,.facet li:hover .count {
  background-color: #2897C5;
  color: #FFF;
  }

.link {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.3;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: .2em;
}

.count {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
  <div class="facet">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="link">
          Name<span class="count">Count</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: there isnt a 'lot' less css, only 3 lines less. and this doesn't answer the question

Comment: Actually, it does answer the question. There is no way to achieve a continuous active-state using only css - you can achieve it with a bit of js, or server side adding of a body-id or something similar, and target that, but you will have to use something else than pure CSS. Also what I mentioned in the comment to the original question. As for "lot less" I guess that was written before edits, and that there was a bit of addition. Too lazy to check such things right now.